# Could "Lips" for Xbox 360 be effectively used to rehearse a song?

Tags: xbox-360, lips

I've got several Karaoke games (American Idol, Rock Band, etc.) for my Xbox 360, but I've heard that [Lips](http://www.xbox.com/en-us/games/l/lips/) lets you import your own MP3 files and play them in the game.

My wife does community theater, and I was thinking for her musical numbers this game would be a good way for her to practice the songs for her plays and perfect her pitch and timing on the songs by importing and playing professional recordings of those songs.

Obviously it doesn't have the lyrics if you import your own sound file (especially for obscure music), but can it detect and show the pitch indicator on the screen for imported songs? Overall, would this game be practical for singing practice on imported songs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Lips keeps track of the score of the imported song you're playing, it detects the pitch and tells you how well are you doing it. I'm not sure if it works correct on 100% of the cases, but overall it seems to do a good job.

I don't do singing, so i couldn't tell you if it works fine to practice your singing skills.

Yes, the game do vocal reduction but I don't remember if you can adjust the level of the reduction.

Comment: Does it detect the original vocals and let you adjust the volume of them up/down so you don't hear them while singing?

Comment: I added the clarification, yes, the game do vocal reduction.