# What are the biggest gameplay differences between Lips and Singstar?

Tags: singstar, lips

I'm trying to decide on a singing/karaoke game and I'm not sure whether to go with Lips or Singstar, as I own both a 360 and a PS3. I was wondering what types of gameplay differences there were between the two games in regards to single player depth and party play, how large the DLC libraries are, and what kind of compatibility between other games the microphones have/accept.

I have a Rock Band 1 microphone, and my entire collection of GH/RB is on 360, so I'm leaning towards Lips for that reason, though I'm not sure if Lips accepts the RB1 mike. [Lips lets you import your own music](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1754/could-lips-for-xbox360-be-effectively-used-to-rehearse-a-song) which I didn't know until I read that question, which is one of the biggest appeals for me. Does Singstar offer the same?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [UltraStar](http://dhost.info/ultrastar/index_en.html), which is a freeware PC clone of Singstar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One difference between the two is that Singstar has a maximum score of 10000 for any one song, whereas the maximum varies hugely between songs on Lips.

This means that Singstar gives you some idea of what a "perfect" play is, but Lips does not.

Also, the waving around the microphone and clapping Lips is just...annoying.